# Error 500 por .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hasta hace un momento estaba trabajando en local y decidí comenzar a trasladarme al servidor para subir la página y me causó un error 500.

Al estar buscando en línea las posibles causas del error 500 encontré algo sobre el archivo .htaccess y decidí cambiarle el nombre para verificar si era este archivo el que causaba el error.

Efectivamente, así es. Sin embargo no puedo eliminarlo, ya que este archivo es el que permite aumentar la capacidad de la subida de archivos principalmente, ya que no tengo manera de modificar el php.ini.

Este el contenido de mi .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 150M
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value memory_limit 250M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 500
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de qué línea debería corregir para evitar el error 500?

Comment: ¿Tu hosting tiene un panel de control para configurar los parámetros de PHP? Por lo que te está pasando deduzco que no está activado el parámetro `FileInfo` de [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/core.html#allowoverride) en el servidor Apache. Cpanel, por ejemplo, tiene dos lugares donde configurar PHP, incluyendo el tamaño máximo del archivo enviado. La única solución es usar las opciones del panel de control o bien contactar con el soporte de tu proveedor para comunicarle este problema. Ellos podrán ofrecerte alternativas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si obtienes 500 Server Error, significa que tu hosting no permite establecer esta configuración global.
Ponte en contacto con tu empresa de alojamiento y pídales que establezcan las opciones de AllowOverride para tu host. 
Algunos no te dan permisos para cambiar los valores en php.ini por tu cuenta y los cambios de htaccess no se aplican.

De todos modos puedes intentar lo siguiente antes, pero seguramente tendrás que hablar con ellos.
Aumente el valor de la siguiente linea.

```
php_value post_max_size 250M
```

Saludos!